# Docker-compose: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose : line 1: Not: command not found

Tags: docker-compose, raspberry-pi, raspbian

i'm trying to install Docker-compose on my Raspberry Pi 3+ which installed Raspbian buster. 
I followed instruction on [docker.com](https://docs.docker.com/v17.12/compose/install/#install-compose). After I entered command : `` sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.20.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose ``.
It show a table for downloading

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYhBI.png)

It seems nothing downloaded, just have a file `docker-compose` saved in `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose`. When I opened it, it empty. Then I enter command `docker-compose -v`, it displayed error `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose : line 1: Not: command not found`.
Anyone have solution?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is because on a raspberry pi the url part of the command results in

```
https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.24.1/docker-compose-Linux-armv7l
```

Looking at the latest stable release at https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.24.1 you can see there is no download for the `armv7l` architecture so the file is empty because there is nothing to download.

Will update answer once I figured out how to install `docker-compose` on Raspian.

**Edit:**

Via `apt-get`. Note: Currently (Nov. 8 2019) this installs version 1.21 which is not the latest available.

```
sudo apt-get install docker-compose
```

Via `pip3`. (Installs latest)

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install docker-compose
```

And then restart your system with

```
sudo shutdown -r
```

Comment: Thank for rep. I've try install by 2 ways, but it did't work, it show that ```sudo: docker-compose: command not found```. But when i enter command without ```sudo```, terminal display ```bash: /usr/local/bin/docker-compose: permission denied```. I go to this folder and it is empty. It seems that path to docker-compose is not exactly, but i don't know where is real path of docker compose.

Comment: If you are still early in the setup I'd recommend simply reinstalling Raspian since your modifications earlier probably broke the PATH variable.

Comment: yea, I did reinstall Raspian, and it worked. I forgot to update for you XD

Answer (score 94):

## UPDATE: 20230829

## Fixed Automating download of latest release of docker-compose

Last update of `curl` apparently didn't like my script to automate the download of the latest release of `docker-compose`. So here's the re-jiggered script which is tested and known to work with Ubuntu 22.04.3. Since GitHub doesn't like IPv6, I forced IPv4 in the
`curl` command.

Obviously if ***not*** using Ubuntu, change the target paths for the download accordingly...

```
#!/bin/bash

DOCKERCOMPOSECURRENTRELEASENUMBER="$(curl -4 -k --http2 https://github.com/docker/compose/releases | grep -m1 '<a href="/docker/compose/releases/download/' | awk -F/ '{print $6}')"

if [[ ! -f /usr/local/bin/docker-compose ]]; then

    curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/"$DOCKERCOMPOSECURRENTRELEASENUMBER"/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

    chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

    docker-compose --version

fi
```

### Intro:

Although `docker-compose` can be installed from a repo per the accepted answer, `apt-cache show docker-compose` reveals that as of 20211201 the repo version is only v1.25; about 2 years behind the current v2.1.1 release. In order to take advantage of more modern docker file versions, I needed to get the Github download working.

### Short Answer:

The Docker [documentation for Docker-Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/) is **WRONG**. They forgot to preface the version number in the command with a "**v**"; consequently the download fails. Apparently this has been wrong for ages...

### Longer Answer:

I ran the below command from the Docker-Compose documentation, and substituted the version "2.1.1" for "1.29.1" per Docker's guidance:

> To install a different version of Compose, substitute 1.29.2 with the
> version of Compose you want to use.

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/2.1.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

The resulting download was 9 KB for a 23 MB binary. Clearly the link was bogus. So I went to the root of the address used in the command  "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases" and right-clicked on the version of Docker-Compose that I wanted and chose "***Copy Link Address***"

This revealed the link Docker was telling folks to use didn't have a "**v**" prefaced before the version number in the `https://` address part of the command.

### Solution:

Preface a "**v**" before the version number you want in the link as below and the command executes successfully:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.1.1/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

BTW, I too was downloading `docker-compose` for a Raspberry Pi using the aarch64 binary for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. However, the missing "**v**" fix for the broken download address should work for any platform.

Comment: Thanks, I found that adding the "v" in the download url fixed the same issue I just encountered.