# Docker-Compose error: "line 1: Not: command not found" when executing --version (Current Version 1.27.4)

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose, raspberry-pi4

Looks like I am having the same issue as this [docker-compose-usr-local-bin-docker-compose-line-1-not-command-not-found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58747879/docker-compose-usr-local-bin-docker-compose-line-1-not-command-not-found) but when I looked at my '/usr/local/bin/docker-compose' file it was not empty. Also when I try the pip install, it said 'Requirement already satisfied: docker-compose in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (1.27.4)' That made me think it was something else.

I am running 64 bit Ubuntu 21.10 server on an RPI 4 with 4gig memory and USB 250gig SSD. I am booting USB. I used the Raspberry Pi Imager v1.6.2 to flash the drive.
The uname -r is '5.13.0-1009-raspi'

I can run 'sudo docker run hello-world:latest' without errors.

Just to be clear, my exact error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ docker-compose --version
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose: line 1: Not: command not found
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Edit:
If my assumption is correct in my answer, then it may have more to do with 64bit arm than Ubuntu. Just in case that is it, I also updated the specs above. I added it was 64 bit Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a different "How to"
[DOCKER ON UBUNTU RASPBERRY PI 4](https://omar2cloud.github.io/rasp/pi/rpidock/)
From what I can remember, seems a lot like other "How to".
There was this one comment.

`Docker does not have a release for Docker-Compose for arm64 yet; however, I have a shell script which will allow us to download a compatible Docker-Compose container with arm64 from my GitHub.`

He had one for 1.28 and one for "the latest" I used the latest

`sudo curl -L --fail https://github.com/AppTower/docker-compose/releases/download/latest/run.sh -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose`

Then when I tried the docker-compose --version I got this:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ docker-compose --version
Unable to find image 'apptower/docker-compose:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from apptower/docker-compose
d2f70382dc9a: Pull complete
3edfa0ca360e: Pull complete
e8fa2c4aadc9: Pull complete
724e91a62418: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:3c6c36c09554b7be4faeb102758f76cb149d703865290a719f6a541ce78851d8
Status: Downloaded newer image for apptower/docker-compose:latest
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build 5becea4c
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Bottom line, I wish I could document for others in the same boat, but I am not sure exactly what it was that fixed it. Just that I was able to see the version. Now back to the project that I need docker for. :-)

Comment: after a lot of searching this was really helpful

Answer (score 11):

In my case, it was a simple version name issue.

I was trying this

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/2.6.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

**2.6.0** -> **v2.6.0**. -- missing "v" letter.

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/v2.6.0/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

Years ago, the version's name didn't include the letter "v."

Comment: This resolved the issue. Was following an old guide that had version without the 'v'. Thanks for bringing this to notice.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue on Centos, the docker-compose file was empty with just one line written "Not Found".I solved this issue by directly downloading the correct version of docker compose file from github which for me was docker-compose-Linux-x86_64. Please Note that "Linux" and "x86_64" depends on your machine specification. You can get them by running $uname -s and $uname -m respectively. After this i made the file executable using $ sudo chmod